# How to install Oracle Java 7 in an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-7, package-managers, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Has anyone one come up with a good config script to install Oracle Java 1.7 in to an Elastic Beanstalk instance using the config files stored in [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html). I am using a tomcat7 version of elastic beanstalk and I was able to install openJDK with yum using the following:

```
packages:
  yum:
    java-1.7.0-openjdk: []
    java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel: []

commands:
  use_java7:
    command: alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

How ever I would like to use Oracle Java 1.7 not OpenJDK and yum does not have that in it's repo natively.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this configuration file

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/install-oracle-jdk.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      wget -O jdk-7u25-linux-x64.rpm --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header 'Cookie:gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm'      
      rpm -Uvh /home/ec2-user/jdk-7u25-linux-x64.rpm
      alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/default/bin/java 3
      alternatives --set java /usr/java/default/bin/java

commands:
  execute-install-oracle-jdk-script:
    command: ./install-oracle-jdk.sh
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
```

Comment: this is not working any more, need to update download link and cookie. it has changed with the new Java 8 launch.

Comment: great work! Thank's a lot! I was too lazy to find this new link. But not lazy to move the rpm to my own CDN server and now I don't need to worry about Oracle changing their downloading system again.

Answer (score 2):

You could alternately install it as you would normally do and use this ami as your ami for creating new ec2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer no longer works, its outdated. This worked for me:

```
# Install Oracle JDK
rpm --erase --nodeps java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
rpm -Uvh .ebextensions/jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/default/bin/java 3
/usr/sbin/alternatives --set java /usr/java/default/bin/java
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java_sdk java_sdk /usr/java/default/bin/java 3
/usr/sbin/alternatives --set java_sdk /usr/java/default/bin/java
```

This is for java 6, since I needed it to be. Also, the jdk downloaded from oracle is actually a bin file now (oracle's custom sh script extractor), so what I did is I downloaded the bin file from oracle, extracted it to get the RPM, and then included the RPM inside the ebextensions.

Just include that sh script to run in an ebextensions config file (google ebextenions config if you're unsure).

Hope this helps somebody.